# SikuliX IDE wait for object to be displayed

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-ide

I use this code to wait for an object in `SikulixIDE 1.1.4-SNAPSHOT`: `wait(Pattern("1548143854795.png").similar(0.7),35)`.
After 15-20 seconds object is present on screen, but it doesn't wait for it. Next `type()` methods are executed without waiting for object.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens if something else is visible on the screen that matches also with a similarity >0.7.

You can check this in the IDE with the Preview feature (click the image).

Programmatically you can highlight the found match:

```
wait(Pattern("1548143854795.png").similar(0.7),35).highlight(3)
```

If something else is found you might try with a higher similarity like 0.95 or even 0.99 (exact match).

[read how SikuliX works](https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basicinfo.html#sikulix-how-does-it-find-images-on-the-screen)